# Need to Add Timezone functionality in my project with Full Calendar

Tags: timezone, fullcalendar, visualforce

I need to implement timezone functionality in my project. I am already using Full Calendar on my Visual force Page.
I am passing eventsList as input to the events attribute which I am getting from the server(Apex). It only works when I change picklist from local to UTC and vice-versa. 
But it does not change for any other Time Zone values.
If I give Full Calendar default JSON i.e - "https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json" to the events attribute. It works as expected for all timezones.

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
        },
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: eventsList,
        loading: function(bool) {
            $('#loading').toggle(bool);
        },
        eventRender: function(event, el) {
            console.log('eventRender');
            // render the timezone offset below the event title
            if (event.start.hasZone()) {
                console.log('hasZone');
                el.find('.fc-title').after(
                    $('<div class="tzo"/>').text(event.start.format('Z'))
                );
            }
        },


        }
    });

    // load the list of available timezones, build the <select> options
    $.getJSON('https://fullcalendar.io/demo-timezones.json', function(timezones) {
        $.each(timezones, function(i, timezone) {
            if (timezone != 'UTC') { // UTC is already in the list
                $('#timezone-selector').append(
                    $("<option/>").text(timezone).attr('value', timezone)
                );
            }
        });
    });       


    // when the timezone selector changes, dynamically change the calendar option
    $('#timezone-selector').on('change', function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'timezone', this.value || false);
    });
```

Below is the structure of my eventslist :

> [{"id":"a014P00001vV9BHQA0","title":"New Event Timezone1","start":"2019-09-17T04:00:00Z","end":"2019-09-17T05:45:00Z","locTZStart":"09/17/2019 12:00 AM","locTZEnd":"09/17/2019 01:45 AM","url":"/apex/EventForm?id=a014P00001vV9BHQA0","editable":false,"durationEditable":true,"startEditable":true,"className":"null","isParked":false,"isDeleted":false,"isNew":"false","presenterCount":0,"roomBooked":"false","roomName":"","typeOfEvent":"Agenda"}]

Comment: have you compared your JSON data to the data from the [fullCalendar events JSON](https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json?start=2019-10-01&end=2019-10-30) to notice any differences which might be important? That would help you with your issue, I think.

Comment: The only major difference I could figure out is of start/end time format. **Full Calendar Json Format**  :`start: '2019-10-16T13:13:55.008+05:30'` ,   **My JSON** :`"start":"2019-09-17T04:00:00Z"` .  And also, could you let me know a better way to log Full Calendar Event JSON? It did not let me log the event list while rendering.

Comment: well, that difference is important. Anyway, what do you mean "a better way"...I can't see how you log them now. Nor can I see where your `eventsList` actually comes from.

Comment: I log event JSON inside eventClick function. `eventsList` is comes from the server. I am using a custom object yo store events data in salesforce. I would like to know how can I log the events JSON while rendering the Calendar.

Comment: `eventsList` is a JavaScript variable. So at some place you must be declaring it and filling it with data. You can log it there. Alternatively if you want to log each event separately as it renders then simply write `console.log(event);` during the "eventRender" callback.